# ¿Cómo crear una nube de palabras basada en un precio (número) de cada palabra?

Tags: python

Me gustaría generar una nube de palabras a partir de un DataFrame con 2 columnas, la primera son los elementos y la segunda los precios. Hago el DataFrame así:

```
articules=["Smartphone", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Headphone", "Workstation", "TV"]
votes=["900", "2000", "1000", "300", "2500", "3000"]
data={'Items': articules, 'Votes': votes}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Tengo importadas las librerías pandas, matplotlib y WordCloud.
Y genero la nube de palabras así

```
text=' '.join(articules)
wc=WordCloud().generate(text)
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()code here
```

Sé que WordCloud genera un nube de palabras según la cantidad en que se repite cada una, o eso he encontrado.
¿Hay alguna manera de generar la nube según el precio de cada artículo? Es decir, que la palabra más grande sea la del precio mayor la menor, la del más bajo.
Pero soy nuevo usando Python, en realidad esto es de un proyecto de clases, así que no conozco a profundidad este lenguaje.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.